# Angular wait for a $http call to execute the next function

Tags: angularjs, http, promise, wait

I had been searching for this same issue here, I found something but all that seems to not be working for me. Let me describe my scenario:

I am adding some features to a Web app done by myself, that Web app is used to manage the developing of the webpage of some customers. Each customer has a webpage and for each customer there are a list of proposals webpages and who of the designers did that proposal, fine.

The list of the developers and be able to see who did what is the new thing in the Web app and the reason of my question, so, the problem is:

Once the web app loads I get the list of developers from the DB and a list of all the customers that have a webpage. So, the next thing the web app does is auto-select the first customer of the list and show its proposals in another list. To do that, the list of the developers is needed, but as it hasnt been still loaded I get the:

> Cannot read property '0' of undefined

When I want to iterate over the `$scope.developers` object

What I do to get the developers is a `$http` call like this:

```
 $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: url,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    }).success(function(data) {
        $scope.developers = data;
    });
```

I know `$http` performs async calls, but i need something that waits until the `$scope.developers` has the data loaded.

The problem comes when I need to use the data supposedly stored in `$scope.developers` but obvously its not. I tried to call the function that uses the `$scope.developers` inside the `.success` function but the same happens.

I tried to use the solution in this thread but I get the same error.

[How to wait till the response comes from the $http request, in angularjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18421830/how-to-wait-till-the-response-comes-from-the-http-request-in-angularjs)

Any help ?? If something in my question is not clear I will try to explain it better.

Comment: "but i need something that waits until the $scope.developers has the data loaded." - no you don't, Angular does 2 way data binding. That's the beauty of it. When you update something you watch you'll get it automatically detected if a digest was triggered (the case here because of the promise). Doing `$scope.developers = []` above the `$http` call like the answer suggests is enough.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, I think I was missing another cool feature from angular, loving Angular again ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please just define `$scope.developers` as empty array before `$http` call ie

```
app.controller("someCtrl", function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.developers = [];
    //....
  $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: url,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
  }).success(function(data) {
    $scope.developers = data;
  });

  //..

});
```

Comment: Did as you suggested and works, first of all thanks for your help. For my short experience I tought that the 2 way data binding only worked fine if the returned data from a $http call or whatever was going to be used in the template and not in the code. Thanks again

Comment: @AlbertPrats $http uses promises internally, whenever a promise resolves in Angular a digest is scheduled.