# AngularJS ajax with PHP json return

Tags: php, ajax, json, angularjs

I am new with php and angularjs ><
I am trying to using ajax to get the data from php but fail

here's my controller

```
angular.module('AA')
    .controller('ExpController', ['$scope', 'Record', '$http', function ($scope,Record, $http) {
    $scope.trans = [];
    $scope.trans = Record.all();
}]);
```

factory.js

```
    angular.module('AA')
    .factory('Record', ['$http',function RecordFactory($http){
      return{
        all: function(){
            return $http.get("./php/getdata.php").success(function (response) {
              return  response;
            });
        }
      }
}]);
```

./php/getdata.php

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
$response=
      ' [
        {id: 0, title: "help", date: "1288323623009", cost: 20, person:"hard", category:"angu", items:[ {name:"item1"},{name:"item2"},{name:"item3"}]},
        {id: 1, title: "hahah", date: "1288323623008", cost: 9.99, person:"Leo", category:"adv"}
      ]';

echo ($response);
?>
```

console said

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token i
>     at Object.parse (native)
>     at fromJson.....

is my json format wrong?

Comment: have you tried an online json validator? there are 100's

Comment: validator said
[    {        id: 0,        title
--------------^
Expecting 'STRING', '}'

should I change it to string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your response isn't JSON, so the JSON parser in the browser is failing.

Property names must be strings. Strings must be delimited with double quotes.

`{id:` ⇨ `{"id":` (and so on for all your other properties).

Use [a linter](http://jsonlint.com/) to test your JSON.

Don't write JSON by hand. Create a PHP data structure and then pass it through [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode).

Comment: so amazing! It's exactly what my problem is, My JSON is wrong!
but it comes out another bug
 $scope.trans  first get  Promise {$$state: Object}
and factory.js return JSON later
should I wait the response like
[this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18421830/how-to-wait-till-the-response-comes-from-the-http-request-in-angularjs)?

Comment: I got the solution!
That's asynchronous problem, just follow [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18421830/how-to-wait-till-the-response-comes-from-the-http-request-in-angularjs). Thank you!!!

Answer (score -2):

This might work.

1.Yes have an ajax call to the php from angular.

```
var responsePromise = $http.get("./php/getdata.php");

responsePromise.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                   //Assign resultJSON to desired variable
                });
```

Comment: There's an ajax call in the code in the question already. It just uses the angular ajax library (which you should definitely be using when you use angular — replacing it with jQuery is not a good idea).

Comment: i tried and it finally no error pop up in console 
but the returned data is not my data in php
it returned     Object {readyState: 1}

thank you for your help!