# how to pause the controller untill the respond return from server?

Tags: model-view-controller, typescript

```
save = () => {
            for (var j = 0; j < this.templatetypes.length; j++) {
                this.template = this.templatetypes[j];
                this.smsTemplate.Template_Type_LSeq = this.template.value;
                this.smsTemplate.SmsCode = this.template.smsCode;
                this.smsTemplate.SmsName = this.template.smsName;
                this.smsTemplate.SmsMessageTemplate = this.template.smsFormat;
                this.smsTemplateSvc.postSmsTemplate(this.smsTemplate).then(() => {
                    return;
                });
            }                      
        }
```

> Blockquote
>   it only pauses the last value for 4 post

Answer (score 0):

You can't really pause the controller in an ajax call. You can have a callback method which will process the returned response.

This line here is wrong.

```
 this.smsTemplateSvc.postSmsTemplate(this.smsTemplate).then(() => {
      return;
 });
```

You are doing a return in the `.then()` promise so as soon as `.postSmsTemplate()` resolves, it does a return and exits immediately.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http has more information on it.

A good example here: [How to wait till the response comes from the $http request, in angularjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18421830/how-to-wait-till-the-response-comes-from-the-http-request-in-angularjs)