# AngularJS - Why I can't get the JSON by $http.get?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox

I'm developing a web application in java with NetBeans
using AngularJS.

When I'm accessing my WebService in localhost I'm getting the JSON array with the objects that I need, working very well

**BUT**

in the controller, I'm not getting the information

Log of the Web browser:

> Result: [object Object]  OR  {}  script.js:140:5
>
> Success/Error: undefined

Code:

```
minhaAplicacao.controller('inicioPacienteCTRL', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.medicoSelecionado;

    var aux;
    var $scope.result = window.console.log($http.get("http://localhost:8080/Clinica5/webresources/medicos")).then(function (success) {
        aux = success;
    }, function (error) {
        aux = error;
    });

    window.console.log("Result: "+$scope.result+ "  OR  "+JSON.stringify($scope.result));
    window.console.log("Success/Error: "+aux);
});
```

And if I put this code in the view I got an error:

```
<div ng-bind="$scope.result"></div>
```

> Error: $scope.result is not defined

I have configured the $routeProvider and is absolutely correct

Thanks a lot <3 Big Hug!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to wait till the response comes from the $http request, in angularjs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18421830/how-to-wait-till-the-response-comes-from-the-http-request-in-angularjs)

Comment: This is happening because of $scope.result will initialize before till response came, it will not wait until response come, that's why.

Answer (score 1):

You can try in the following way.

```
minhaAplicacao.controller('inicioPacienteCTRL', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.functionName = function(){
        //define
        $scope.medicoSelecionado = {};  
        $http.get("http://localhost:8080/Clinica5/webresources/medicos").then(function (success) {
            console.log(success);
            //success data passed 
            $scope.medicoSelecionado = success;

        }, function (error) {
            console.log(error);
            //error message
            $scope.error = error;
        });

    }
});
```

And use this html to display error

```
<div class="error">{{error}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign your response to controller scope variable result as a result of asynch request like this

```
 $scope.result = success
```

MoreOver you can avoid using var when declaring $scope variables

```
minhaAplicacao.controller('inicioPacienteCTRL', function ($scope, $http) {
$scope.medicoSelecionado;

$scope.aux = {};
$scope.result {}; 
$http.get("http://localhost:8080/Clinica5/webresources/medicos").then(function (success) {
    $scope.result = success;
}, function (error) {
    $scope.aux = error;
});

window.console.log("Result: ",$scope.result, "  OR  ",JSON.stringify($scope.result));
window.console.log("Success/Error:",$scope.aux);
```

});

also in view

```
 <div ng-bind="result"></div>
```

no need of $scope

Answer (score 0):

Try `<div ng-model="result"></div>` for the second error.

And no need to do:

```
$scope.medicoSelecionado;
$scope.aux;
$scope.result;
```

Just use a new model when you need one; no declaration is needed.

Doing `$scope.result = success`in your .then() should be fine, as suggested by Vinod Louis.

The way I would do it:

```
minhaAplicacao.controller('inicioPacienteCTRL', function ($scope, $http) {

    $http.get("http://localhost:8080/Clinica5/webresources/medicos")

    .then(function (success) {
                $scope.result = success;
            }, function (error) {
                $scope.result = error;
            });

    window.console.log("Result: "+$scope.result+ "  OR  "+JSON.stringify($scope.result));

});
```

What does `aux` do by the way?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define `var aux = {}` because if you not defined anything then it will show undefined
and you are getting object in success so that it is showing `[object, object]`

```
minhaAplicacao.controller('inicioPacienteCTRL', function ($scope, $http) {
$scope.medicoSelecionado;

var aux = {};
var $scope.result = window.console.log($http.get("http://localhost:8080/Clinica5/webresources/medicos")).then(function (success) {
    aux = success;
}, function (error) {
    aux = error;
});

window.console.log("Result: "+$scope.result+ "  OR  "+JSON.stringify($scope.result));
window.console.log("Success/Error: "+aux);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

GOT!

For some reason was having conflict with the route 'login'. I don't known why.

The solution was deleting the redirectTo line

```
when('/inicioMedico', {
     templateUrl: 'inicioMedico.html',
     controller: "inicioMedicoCTRL"
}).
otherwise ({
    // redirectTo: 'login' ERROR HERE
});
```