# Angular $scope variable is empty and not updated after setting it in HTTP GET

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, http-get

I have `$scope.participants = []` as a global variable. My problem is when I used this variable in another function after calling the function below. `$scope.participants` is empty. However, it isn't when I checked the `response.data`.

```
$scope.getParticipants = function(seminar_id,seminar_name,seminar_code) {
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        params: { 'seminar_id' : seminar_id },
        url: 'getParticipants'
      }).then(function(response) {
          $scope.participants=response.data;
      });
  }
```

Comment: do you see any errors in console

Comment: `$http` is the asynchronous call. `$scope.participants` is empty before `$http` returns the data.

Comment: Check whether this can solve your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18421830/how-to-wait-till-the-response-comes-from-the-http-request-in-angularjs

Comment: @RogerNg Oh, now I understand! THANKSS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can check out this working [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/ATlhJvXgW3K0JVMqQCJm?p=preview), you need wait until your promise resolve.

```
$scope.getParticipants= function(seminar_id,seminar_name,seminar_code){
$http({
    method: 'GET', 
    dataType: 'JSON',
    params: { 'seminar_id' : seminar_id },
    url: 'getParticipants'
  }).then(function(response) {
      $scope.participants=response.data;
      $scope.callBack();
      console.log(response.data);
  });
}
$scope.getParticipants('a','b','c');
```

Comment: There's no surity that it will complete in 1 sec

Comment: I tried this too and it wouldn't get completed in 1 sec.

Comment: Added call back to notify some function call in the scope on completion of async call. check updated [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/ATlhJvXgW3K0JVMqQCJm?p=preview)